# Rails, I18n, Labels, Default translation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, label, yaml

Is there any way to set a default label. Lets say I have 5 models all with the attribute Email and I want them all to have the same translation.

**sv.yaml**

```
sv:        
  helpers:
    label:
      defaults:
        email: "E-post"
```

This does not work.

Comment: how about putting `email` to the top level? should work, IIRC.

Answer (score 0):

```
label(:post, :title)
# => <label for="post_title">Title</label>

 helpers:
  label:
    post:
      body: "Write your entire text here"
```

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/label

Comment: This doesn't help me if I have 5 different models with the same attribute and I want to make them fetch one translation of that attribute instead of 5.

Comment: @Philip translation for models http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#translations-for-active-record-models

Comment: ???? I know about the translation for models. Thats not what Im asking for. Have you read my q?!

Comment: @Philip
 so you  can do simple translation 

  
`sv:
 your_key: your value
 email: your translation

on view
label: t('your_key')` will output label: your value

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to an existing yaml label by prefixing the path to an existing translation with a colon ':'. For example, in my tables I have a general section with often-used labels:

```
coding_systems:
  code:         'Code'
  note:         'Remark'
```

Later, I refer back to these like this:

```
attributes:
  a1_code:
    code:      :coding_systems.code
    note:      :coding_systems.note
  a2_code:
    code:      :coding_systems.code
    note:      :coding_systems.note
```